# “Author Registration by 20 Oct 2014” --- does it include 20 Oct. 2014?

Tags: dates

I am registering for a conference as an author. The deadline  information says "Author Registration by 20 Oct 2014". Can I register it tomorrow, which is 20 Oct. 2014?

Comment: We get so many of these type of questions. Why? And why not simply check with the organisers?

Comment: It's certainly a duplicate, but I feel that the accepted answer in the linked question isn't a good one - it gives an answer based on logical parsing, while ignoring the ambiguity of common usage.

Comment: The accepted answer is only the answer which helped the asker of that question. It doesn't mean that every other asker has to choose that answer. Or, indeed, that other answers cannot be added.

Comment: @Avner: I don't believe that common usage is ambiguous. If something has to be done *by* a date, it has to be done on or before that date. The only ambiguity is: by what **time** on that date must it be done?

Comment: @PeterShor Exactly. It can be parsed as "by the beginning of the day" or "the end of the day", so the linked answer's claim that "it includes the day" isn't really meaningful.

Comment: @Avner: It's not usually parsed *"by the beginning of the day"*. But certainly both *"by the close of business hours on that day"* and *"by midnight on that day"* are common.

Comment: @PeterShor I've seen cases where "by the 5th" means that the receiving end needs the information *on* the 5th. "We are updating all records on the 5th, so any update forms must be submitted by then" would imply that.